# How did I make custom tag?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've already make a component like following.

in MyButton.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Theme, makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

interface IMyButton {
  title: string,
}

export default function Parent(props: IMyButton) {
  return (
    <Button>
      {props.title}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

in App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import MyButton from './MyButton'

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyButton title="title" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It works well as I expect.
But I'd like to make a custom tag to use like following

```
<MyButton>title</MyButton>
```

I don't know which documents should I refer.

If you want to give me a solution, please don't use class, but typescript and function.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `MyButton.tsx` to

```
interface IMyButton {
  children: React.ReactNode,
}

export default function Parent(props: IMyButton) {
     return (
       <Button>
         {props.children}
       </Button>
     );
    }
```

and you can use

```
<MyButton>title</MyButton>
```

Comment: Could you give me some more advice? I changed code refering your answer, But it doesn't work with compile error. https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-dawn-keuj5

Comment: Okay, I solved my problem after seeing your code being changed. Thank you.